# Returning result of Sheet1.ColumnB to Sheet2.ColumnB given a certain value exists in any cell for Sheet1.ColumnC

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a problem.  I have something akin to this in Sheet1, where I have multiple instances of the same term with different (or sometimes non-existent) definitions:

```
     Term Name    Definition      Chosen Definition?           
     Account      The account.      
     Account      
     Account      An account name.        x
```

Sheet2 is a reference sheet with all of the unique term names, but no definitions as of yet.

```
    Term Name     Definition
    Account
    Product
    Customer
```

Since I have so many duplicates of the same term in Sheet1, I am trying to write something where I can simply put an 'x' in the third column ('Chosen Definition?') to mark the definition that I have chosen, and it will take the adjacent definition cell from Sheet1 (in Column B), and put it into the right spot in Sheet2 like so:

```
    Term Name     Definition
    Account       An account name.
    Product
    Customer
```

I assume this would be done either by combining something like an IF statement, an AND statement, and a VLOOKUP, or in VBA (which I'm not an expert in at all).  I've tried both methods and I feel like I've gotten somewhat close, but not quite there.  Here's my VBA code:

```
    Sub InputData()
        Dim c as Range
        Dim j as Integer
        Dim Source as Worksheet
        Dim Target as Worksheet

        Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        j = 2
        For Each c in Source.Range("C3:C1000")
            If c = "x"
                Source.Rows(c.Rows).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
    End Sub
```

That just puts any row with an 'x' in column C at the beginning of Sheet2:

```
    Term Name     Definition
    Account       An account name.
    Account
    Product
    Customer
```

Am I getting close with the VBA code that I have?  I don't think that formulas will work since I believe that what I am looking for needs to loop through each cell to find a match, but I don't want to add a new row each time I find a match.

Comment: you are overwriting Source variable in the above. It will end up as Sheet2. I think you mean it to be Target but that is a bad variable name as is part of event based structures.

Comment: Yes you are correct...sorry, I was copying this from another machine, will change to reflect what it actually is.

Comment: change to something like wsTarget and wsSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a formula. For example, in C2 sheet2, with your data as shown in A1:C4 sheet1

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(A2&"x",Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,0))
```

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You could wrap in an `IFERROR(formula,"")` to mask any non matches.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm getting a value error when I try it but I'll try playing around with this.

Comment: You would get that either if value not found , or you haven’t entered the formula using ctrl + shift + enter. Then {} will appear around the formula.